# Node Promise is Resolving and Rejecting

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have a basic promise in a TypeScript method. I can't i figure out why it is both resolving and rejecting in one call.

Here is the method

```
async getProductNew() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Make call to get product");
        getProduct(this.upcCode).then((response: ProductDto) => 
            console.log("resolved in get product");
            this.productDto = response;
            resolve();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Rejected in Get Product");
            errorResponse.message = `Unexpected error: ${error}`;
            reject(errorResponse);
        });
    });
}
```

and here is what it calls

```
async getProduct(upcCode: string): Promise<ProductDto> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject(errorResponse);
    });
}
```

When I check my console, it shows both the resolve and reject are being called.

How is this even possible?

Comment: Why are you wrapping a promise in another promise?

Comment: when i execute the code i get "Make call to get product" "Rejected in Get Product". So looks like it works fine.